# React Day Picker only changing "to" state on second click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-day-picker

all...I'm using the 'react-day-picker' component to choose a range of dates via two inputs.

I started by using, verbatim, the example on this page: http://react-day-picker.js.org/examples/input-from-to. The only alterations I made was the add `console.log(this.state)` to the `handleFromChange` and `handleToChange` methods.

The component seems to work at first glance, but when I console.log the state, I found that the "to" state is only being updated the *second* time a "to" date is selected in the picker. Selecting a "to" date the first time returns "undefined."

Looking at this code, is there anything that jumps out as incorrect? Again, this code was provided by the creator of the component. I'm trying to figure out if its a bug with the component, a bug with the example code, or some other problem.

Thanks!

For convenience, here's the code I'm using:

```
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

import DayPickerInput from 'react-day-picker/DayPickerInput';
import 'react-day-picker/lib/style.css';

import { formatDate, parseDate } from 'react-day-picker/moment';

export default class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleFromChange = this.handleFromChange.bind(this);
    this.handleToChange = this.handleToChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      from: undefined,
      to: undefined,
    };
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
  }
  focusTo() {
    // Focus to `to` field. A timeout is required here because the overlays
    // already set timeouts to work well with input fields
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => this.to.getInput().focus(), 0);
  }
  showFromMonth() {
    const { from, to } = this.state;
    if (!from) {
      return;
    }
    if (moment(to).diff(moment(from), 'months') < 2) {
      this.to.getDayPicker().showMonth(from);
    }
  }
  handleFromChange(from) {
    // Change the from date and focus the "to" input field
    this.setState({ from }, () => {
      if (!this.state.to) {
        this.focusTo();
      }
    });
  }
  handleToChange(to) {
    this.setState({ to }, this.showFromMonth);
  }
  render() {
    const { from, to } = this.state;
    const modifiers = { start: from, end: to };
    return (
      <div className="InputFromTo">
        <DayPickerInput
          value={from}
          placeholder="From"
          format="LL"
          formatDate={formatDate}
          parseDate={parseDate}
          dayPickerProps={{
            selectedDays: [from, { from, to }],
            disabledDays: { after: to },
            toMonth: to,
            modifiers,
            numberOfMonths: 2,
          }}
          onDayChange={this.handleFromChange}
        />{' '}
        —{' '}
        <span className="InputFromTo-to">
          <DayPickerInput
            ref={el => (this.to = el)}
            value={to}
            placeholder="To"
            format="LL"
            formatDate={formatDate}
            parseDate={parseDate}
            dayPickerProps={{
              selectedDays: [from, { from, to }],
              disabledDays: { before: from },
              modifiers,
              month: from,
              fromMonth: from,
              numberOfMonths: 2,
            }}
            onDayChange={this.handleToChange}
          />
        </span>
        <Helmet>
          <style>{`
  .InputFromTo .DayPicker-Day--selected:not(.DayPicker-Day--start):not(.DayPicker-Day--end):not(.DayPicker-Day--outside) {
    background-color: #f0f8ff !important;
    color: #4a90e2;
  }
  .InputFromTo .DayPicker-Day {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
  }
  .InputFromTo .DayPicker-Day--start {
    border-top-left-radius: 50% !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50% !important;
  }
  .InputFromTo .DayPicker-Day--end {
    border-top-right-radius: 50% !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50% !important;
  }
  .InputFromTo .DayPickerInput-Overlay {
    width: 550px;
  }
  .InputFromTo-to .DayPickerInput-Overlay {
    margin-left: -198px;
  }
`}</style>
        </Helmet>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code. It looks like it receives proper value in the state for both the two value **To** and **From**. Maybe you have console.log(this.state) at the wrong place.

Let me tell you that **setState** method is asynchronous so you must be getting the wrong values.

I've added a console.log statement at appropriate state to show you that the value is reflected right. Have a look at below code

```js
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

import DayPickerInput from 'react-day-picker/DayPickerInput';
import 'react-day-picker/lib/style.css';

import { formatDate, parseDate } from 'react-day-picker/moment';

export default class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleFromChange = this.handleFromChange.bind(this);
        this.handleToChange = this.handleToChange.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            from: undefined,
            to: undefined,
        };
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    }
    focusTo() {
        // Focus to `to` field. A timeout is required here because the overlays
        // already set timeouts to work well with input fields
        this.timeout = setTimeout(() => this.to.getInput().focus(), 0);
    }
    showFromMonth() {
        console.log("value from the state",this.state);
        const { from, to } = this.state;
        if (!from) {
            return;
        }
        if (moment(to).diff(moment(from), 'months') < 2) {
            this.to.getDayPicker().showMonth(from);
        }
    }
    handleFromChange(from) {
        console.log("New From value", from);
        // Change the from date and focus the "to" input field
        this.setState({ from }, () => {
            console.log("value from the state",this.state);
            if (!this.state.to) {
                this.focusTo();
            }
        });
    }
    handleToChange(to) {
        console.log("New To value", to);
        this.setState({ to }, this.showFromMonth);
    }
    render() {
        const { from, to } = this.state;
        const modifiers = { start: from, end: to };
        return (
            <div className="InputFromTo">
                <DayPickerInput
                    value={from}
                    placeholder="From"
                    format="LL"
                    formatDate={formatDate}
                    parseDate={parseDate}
                    dayPickerProps={{
                        selectedDays: [from, { from, to }],
                        disabledDays: { after: to },
                        toMonth: to,
                        modifiers,
                        numberOfMonths: 2,
                    }}
                    onDayChange={this.handleFromChange}
                />{' '}
                —{' '}
                <span className="InputFromTo-to">
          <DayPickerInput
              ref={el => (this.to = el)}
              value={to}
              placeholder="To"
              format="LL"
              formatDate={formatDate}
              parseDate={parseDate}
              dayPickerProps={{
                  selectedDays: [from, { from, to }],
                  disabledDays: { before: from },
                  modifiers,
                  month: from,
                  fromMonth: from,
                  numberOfMonths: 2,
              }}
              onDayChange={this.handleToChange}
          />
        </span>
                <Helmet>
                    <style>{`
  .InputFromTo .DayPicker-Day--selected:not(.DayPicker-Day--start):not(.DayPicker-Day--end):not(.DayPicker-Day--outside) {
    background-color: #f0f8ff !important;
    color: #4a90e2;
  }
  .InputFromTo .DayPicker-Day {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
  }
  .InputFromTo .DayPicker-Day--start {
    border-top-left-radius: 50% !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50% !important;
  }
  .InputFromTo .DayPicker-Day--end {
    border-top-right-radius: 50% !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50% !important;
  }
  .InputFromTo .DayPickerInput-Overlay {
    width: 550px;
  }
  .InputFromTo-to .DayPickerInput-Overlay {
    margin-left: -198px;
  }
`}</style>
                </Helmet>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer...the asynchronous nature of state gave me the clue I needed.I was being too literal, trying to trigger a method at the end of the 'handleToChange' method. What I should have done, and what worked, was to trigger my method in this handler's setState callback. That worked fine. (I'm basically populating a table with data that depends on the "from" and "to" date being passed as query parameters).